# How to Filldown activecell in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Could anyone help me? Let's say `I4:I` is my Lastrow and Activecell in G will fill down the formula.

```
Dim Lastrowzxc As Long
Lastrowzxc = Range("I4").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[2]<0,""40"",""50"")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell.Address & Lastrowzxc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it works for me:

```
Dim Lastrowzxc As Long
Lastrowzxc = ActiveSheet.Range("I4").currentRegion.Rows.Count

Range("G" & ActiveSheet.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[2]<0,""40"",""50"")"

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range(ActiveCell.Address), Cells(Lastrowzxc, ActiveCell.Column))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect address in 'Range' of autofill. This might work, but this is far from perfect (just a starting point to get you going):

```
Dim Lastrowzxc As Long
Lastrowzxc = Range("I4").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[2]<0,""40"",""50"")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(Lastrowzxc, ActiveCell.Column))
```

Comment: i try the code but its says Autofil method of range class failed.

Comment: what is the value of Lastrowzxc?

Comment: Range("I4").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count  , the last cell in "I" have value.

Comment: That I can see. What is the actual value (number). How many rows do you have in your region?

Comment: the value number of my rows is not fixed , it depends on our extracted row files.

Comment: I understand that :) but when you get the error - what is the number of rows?

Comment: Hi Sir Pawel - thank you for answering my question. i got it thank  you so much! i already resolved! :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `I4:I20` is the range to fill and `G4` contains the formula, this is what you should do:

```
Range("I4:I20").FormulaR1C1 = Range("G4").FormulaR1C1
```

Comment: there's no specific last range sir Van.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother selecting ranges? It's bad practice.

I don't quite understand what your goal is as you are selecting the cell below the last cell in col G. I suppose you want to start at the last row of col G until the last row for col I? If so..:

```
With Workbooks("REFERENCE").Sheets("REFERENCE")
LastrowI = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
LastrowG = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

.Range("G" & LastrowG).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[2]<0,""40"",""50"")" 'change Range if necessary
.Range("G" & LastrowG).FormulaR1C1.AutoFill Destination:= .Range("G" & LastrowG & ":G" & LastrowI)

End With
```